# Is Nuxt.js (not pure Vue) check

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

Is there a way to check is Nuxt.js is being used?

### Why I need to do it

For the UI frameworks development, herewith it's unknown will be used with Nuxt.js or just pure Vue. For example, depending on Vue or Nuxt, we need different link component:

```html
<component is="isNuxt ? 'nuxt-link' : 'router-link'" />
```

What it the implementation of `isNuxt` method?

Comment: I don't know if there's any specific variable/function you call call to check that, but since nuxt is built on top of vue, you could just use the basic vue components like `router-link`, it will work just fine.
If you really need to check for more complex components, you could try check for things like `useNuxtApp` or some specific hook, if it doesn't exists then it's just vue

Answer (score 2):

I think the easy way could be:

```
const isNuxt = () => !!window.$nuxt
```